# Trying to dockerize a sails js project

Tags: node.js, docker, sails.js, docker-compose

I am trying to create a project for `sails js` using Docker and Docker Compose. What I want is to generate the `sails` code inside Docker and generate the structure in the current directory.

When I try to generate it, as the directory is not empty because I have a `Dockerfile` and a `docker-compose.yml`, I'm getting an error saying that the directory is not empty.

This is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:8.9.3

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g sails
RUN sails new .
RUN sails lift
```

With this configuration I get the error of current directory not empty.

Thinking about it I tried generating the code and the copying it.

```
...

RUN npm install -g sails
RUN sails new .

# I do the COPY after generating the code
COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN sails lift
```

This seems to work because I don't get any error in my local environment I don't have the generated code.

Maybe this process is wrong and I should install it as a dependency and then run with `docker-compose` a container to generate the code, but I think I will have the same problem about trying to generate the code in a non empty directory.

Comment: I'm confused  as to what you are trying to accomplish. The `sails new` command would be creating the source code that you are already copying from the build context. I would think that you do one or the other (not both). If the project was already created locally with `sails new`, then why run it at `docker build` time?

Comment: Maybe it's not correct to generate the `sails` code inside Docker. Probably I should do it in local and copy them in the Docker image. But the problem I have if that I don't want to use the local node, I want to install it using Docker but I have the problem that I can't generate the code in the current directory because it's not empty.

Comment: in your 2nd iteration you need to add this `WORKDIR /usr/src/app`  after the COPY

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do... Maybe you can confirm it (and then I can create a proper answer for a suggestion on how to approach). You essentially want to avoid installing Sails (and Node) on the host and instead use a Docker container to generate the Sails code (`sails init`) and then build an image using that code?

Comment: @AndyShinn Yeah, that's what I want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an idea that uses two separate images. One image is your Sails utility image and the other will be the actual application.

## Utility Image

First, the Sails utility image. This is pretty straightforward. It is just an image based on Node.js with Sails installed. Create the following `Dockerfile` in a new directory:

```
FROM node:8.9.3
RUN npm install -g sails
WORKDIR /usr/src/app  
ENTRYPOINT ["sails"]
```

Then build it:

```
docker build -t sails .
```

This could even be a public image. There isn't anything specific to your project here. We are just going to use it to do `sails` commands.

## Application

Now, create another new folder and navigate into it. It will need to be empty. Create the new sails project with a command like:

```
docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/usr/src/app sails new .
```

This will create the Sails project in the current directory using the utility image. This is the root of our new Sails project.

Let's create the `Dockerfile` and `.dockerignore` file for this Sails project. For this, we'll just rely on the `-onbuild` variant of the `node` image to handle most of the heavy lifting. Create the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:8.9.3-onbuild
EXPOSE 1337
```

And also the accompanying `.dockerignore` file:

```
node_modules
```

Now we can build the application:

```
docker build -t myproject
```

After the application is build we can launch it using:

```
docker run -p 1337:1337 myproject
```

The `-onbuild` variant of the Node.js image will do the `npm install` for us and has `npm start` as the default command. The default Sails `package.json` sets the `start` script to run the application using `node app.js`. See https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/8/onbuild/Dockerfile for more information on what it does.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, that's great!